# python-ldap login to Active Directory always says Invalid Credentials

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

```
>>> import ldap
>>> conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://zion.karunya.edu')
>>> conn.protocol_version = 3
>>> conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
>>> conn.simple_bind_s('username', 'password')
```

The last line always raises the annoying `InvalidCredentials` exception. I'm sure that the password is right. I even tried other username, password combinations (of my friends).

Also note that a friend who is using PHP `adLDAP` plugin faces no problem. And I've spent hours trying to figure out this stupid problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument to `conn.simple_bind_s()` has a more complex format than just a string with a username. It needs a distinguished name as the first arg. Example of distinguished name: `username@example.com`.
For more details you can look [here](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/python-ldap-applications-part-2-ldap-opearations) and [here](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-dn.html).

Comment: Thanks! It did work after adding the domain name to the username like `username@karunya.edu`. Please add that detail so that I can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind the user using complete DN.
for example

USERNAME = 'CN=abc,OU=abc,DC=abc,DC=abc,DC=com'

I hope this helps.